# Codingbat problems -- String

Tags: java

I came across a question on codingbat and the question is:

Given a string, return a new string made of 3 copies of the last 2 chars of the original string. The string length will be at least 2.
I solved the problem and the solution (below) is a better than mine, however, there is a problem with the solution code, when the string length is less than 2, say the length is only 1. str index will be -1. will the code still work? why does the site say the solution is correct?

```
 public String extraEnd(String str) {
      String end = str.substring(str.length()-2);
      return end + end + end;
```

Comment: *"why does the site say the solution is correct?"* -> *"The string length will be at least 2"* ... why do you ignore that rule?

Comment: When you say last *two characters*, you kind of assume that the `String` will have at least 2 `chars`.

Comment: ok, this code is correct in this case, I was thinking of a situation where there was no such rule given.

Comment: @Kingsfull123 in that case either the question is not framed or you have to check for corner cases.

Comment: Real world coding is full of situations in which you know certain things about the input will be true, so you don't have to code for the situation where they're false. For example, if you never call a private method with `null` as a parameter, your method doesn't need to handle nulls. Or, you're using a Web Service framework that validates input model objects -- do your processing code doesn't need to handle situations where a field isn't valid. In this case, the requirements state that the string length will be at least 2. The solution only needs to deal with those inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The website will try to give you as many tests as possible to make sure it's mostly free of bugs, however some do slip through the crack and make exceptions. The code below is one that works through all tests given if you want to give it a go;

```
public String extraFront(String str) {
    if (str.length() <= 2)
    return str+str+str;
return str.substring(0,2)+str.substring(0,2)+str.substring(0,2);
}
```

It seems that you're correct with the code, the index would be -1. Maybe follow it up with the challenge on String 2, it'll come in handy. Wish you best of luck!